# Merging 1000 PDF thru iText throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, itext, out-of-memory

I am trying to merge 1000 PDF Files thru iText. I am not sure where the memory leakage is happening. Below is the sample code. Note that i am removing the child-pdf file as soon as i merge to the parent file. Please pointout bug in below code or is there any better way to do this with out memory conception. This process is done thru servlet (not standalone program)

```
FileInputStream local_fis = null;
BufferedInputStream local_bis = null;
File localFileObj = null;
for(int taIdx=0;taIdx<totalSize;taIdx++){
    frObj = (Form3AReportObject)reportRows.get(taIdx);
    localfilename = companyId + "_" +  frObj.empNumber + ".pdf";

    local_fis = new FileInputStream(localfilename);
    local_bis = new BufferedInputStream(local_fis); 
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(local_bis);

    cb = pdfWriter.getDirectContent(); 
    document.newPage();
    page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    local_bis.close();
    local_fis.close();

    localFileObj = new File(localfilename);
    localFileObj.delete();
}
document.close();
```

Comment: new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filename), null) - Contrary to the other constructors only the xref is read into memory. The reader is said to be working in "partial" mode as only parts of the pdf are read as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to try something like the following (exception handling, file close and delete removed for clarity):

```
for(int taIdx = 0; taIdx < totalSize; taIdx++) {
    Form3AReportObject frObj = (Form3AReportObject)reportRows.get(taIdx);

    localfilename = companyId + "_" +  frObj.empNumber + ".pdf";

    FileInputStream local_fis = new FileInputStream(localfilename);

    pdfWriter.freeReader(new PdfReader(local_fis));

    pdfWriter.flush();
}

pdfWriter.close();
```

Comment: Excellent!! here is where the memory leak was. 
The missing line was pdfWriter.freeReader().
Now no need to increase the javaheap. It works. Thanks

Comment: I found one more solution without using pdfwriter. 

for(int taIdx=0;taIdx<totalSize;taIdx++){ 

frObj = (Form3AReportObject)reportRows.get(taIdx); 

localfilename = companyId + "_" + frObj.empNumber + ".pdf"; 

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(localfilename); 

document.setPageSize(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1)); 

PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfCopy.getImportedPage(reader, 1); 

pdfCopy.addPage(pdfImportedPage); 

reader.close(); 

}

Answer (score 1):

Who says there is a memory leak? Your merged document needs to fit into memory in its entirety, there's no way around it, and it may well be larger than the default heap size of 64MB *in memory* (rather than on disc).

I don't see a problem with your code, but if you want to diagnose it in detail, [use visualvm's heap profiler](http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html) (comes with the JDK since Java 6 update 10 or so).

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion Micheal. I will check heap profiler and update my findings

Comment: Hey Micheal i tried to use visualvm but cannot connect to remote. Started a new thread for this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263991/conntecting-remote-tomcat-jmx-instance-using-jconsole

Comment: @micheal there is flush() method on PdfWriter & PdfCopy which "Flushes the BufferedOutputStream". So I don't think the entire merged file needs to fit in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PdfUtils {
     public static void concatFiles(File file1, File file2, File fileOutput) throws Exception {
          List<File> islist =  new ArrayList<File>();
          islist.add(file1);
          islist.add(file2);

          concatFiles(islist, fileOutput);
         }

         public static void concatFiles(List<File> filelist, File fileOutput) throws Exception {
          if (filelist.size() > 0) {
                 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream( filelist.get(0)) );
                 Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));

           PdfCopy cp = new PdfCopy(document,  new FileOutputStream( fileOutput ));

           document.open();


           for (File file : filelist ) {

                PdfReader r = new PdfReader( new FileInputStream( file));
                for (int k = 1; k <= r.getNumberOfPages(); ++k) {
                    cp.addPage(cp.getImportedPage(r, k));
                }
                cp.freeReader(r);

           }
           cp.close();
           document.close();
          } else{             
           throw new Exception("La lista dei pdf da concatenare è vuota");        
          }               
         }
   }
```

Comment: Why do you use the Document(Rectangle pageSize) constructor?

Comment: Honestly I don t remember, pheraps because of rotate PDF cases

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing max heap size from the default (which is only 64mb)?

See:

- [How to deal with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s)
- [Java How To ...: 6 Common Errors in Setting Java Heap Size](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html)

Comment: Increasing heap size wont help. Because this process will run in Servlet environment and several request may come. So we need to find out the memory leakage.

Comment: And what leads you to say that? How do you know that your current settings are good enough? Have you analyzed the memory needs of this code and the application as a whole?

Comment: I am thinking the current settings is good enough and the current code "must" work efficiently with this settings as i am writing page by page in to the stream (not storing in memory)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - if the current settings were good enough, then why are you getting OutOfMemoryErrors? It looks like you add more objects/data onto your pdfWriter and PDF document with each iteration. This implies that it is growing in size per PDF.

Comment: Instead of assuming that a solution wouldn't work, how about experimenting with it and finding out for sure? The question about increasing max heap size from the default was meant to be the first troubleshooting step. When you are having heap size issues, the first step on any checklist has to be "have you changed the settings from the default?"

Comment: No i didn't try increasing the heap size. I will try that and also i will try  "Michael Rutherfurd's" idea.

Comment: Hello Matt, Please check out the below comment. The code runs without increasing HEAP Size.

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't use InputStream? If you can, try using just the path for you file on 'new PDFReader("/somedirectory/file.").

This make the reader to act on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is trying to create a `PdfContentByte` object (`cb`) within the loop.  Moving it outside might fix the issue.  I used similar code in my application to stitch together 13k individual PDFs in to one PDF without trouble.

Comment: And where is that? Implicitly? If so where? A bit more information would be helpful

Answer (score -2):

Instead of merging 1000 PDFs, try to create a zip of them.