# How to access the liferay tomcat server in cloud using JConsole

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay

I have a liferay tomcat server bundle in my cloud. How can I monitor the threads using JConsole.

Regards,
Shahbaz Khan.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263991/connecting-remote-tomcat-jmx-instance-using-jconsole

Comment: In the question i was asking to monitor on cloud.
All setting i did but how to connect to remote server using JConsole.

Comment: http://muzso.hu/2008/11/28/connecting-to-a-tomcat-instance-with-jconsole    http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-connect-jconsole-tomcat-running-service  hope it helps.

Comment: i was asking if the tomcat is on cloud.
How to access it using JConsole. It was working fine in my local tomcat server.

Comment: The question that Mohammad Adil has linked to gives quite a lot of options. If that doesn't match what you need to know, you'll have to give a bit more information on what you did and what does not work for you