# VisualVM for profiling an application running on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war, visualvm

I have apache tomcat 7 running on local and a web application deployed as .war file to this server. I am trying to use visualvm to profile the application but so far I am only able to profile tomcat itself.

I am able to see everything about tomcat in the interface and there are absolutely no problems. I am able to see indvidiual tomcat functions as well  which are of no meaning to me.

What I want to see is the execution time of the functions of my deployed web application, in other words my own code. But I am unable to do that? Has anyone ever managed to do this profiling? Do I need to set a JMX connections or something with my deployed application? Below you can find my screen which I am able to profile tomcat functions.

[image: My VisualVM screen which I am able to profile tomcat]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter methods displayed in "profiler". 
but what you want is "sampler".

Here is what you should do.

Before you run sampler. You must **check** the "settings" checkbox on right of profiling window.

It will show you settings where you can write what packages should be profiled.

for example:

> com.myCompany.module.*

[image: profiler]

Comment: I tried that now and I am still unable to get any results for the functions I want. The thing is, should I be able to see my functions (com.mycompany.. ) while I am connected to local tomcat instance. Or do I need to create a connections straight to my running application to be able to profile it?

Comment: I am assuming your server is on localhost. You should be able to see method executions withoud any additional settings. Try use another tool shipped with java - JMC - java mission control  or if you want to try [setup JMX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263991/connecting-remote-tomcat-jmx-instance-using-jconsole)

Comment: ok Marek I will try that. Although I set the filters, I am not able to see any actual method executions with this one. When I set the filter it is just blank and VM is not able to match any functions with my filter.

Comment: yep the sample with the filters are working fine. This will be good enough for me, thanks a lot. So if you can just add that to your response that attaching to apache process is just enough for monitoring applications deployed on it, I will select you response as the correct response and hopefully no one would lose half a day for investigating that issue again :)