# How can i connect with jconsole to ActiveMQ jmx?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx, vpn, jconsole

I try configure jmx according this instruction: http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
On localhost all works well. But when i try connect to FreeBSD server over VPN jconsole can't establish connection.

I use such settings for ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START variable:

ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_BASE}/conf/jmx.password

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_BASE}/conf/jmx.access

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=vpn_id_address

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"

What i do wrong?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263991/connecting-remote-tomcat-jmx-instance-using-jconsole or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151238/has-anyone-ever-got-a-remote-jmx-jconsole-to-work .

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm the port is listening, using netstat or other tool.

> netstat -na | grep 1616
> ... should show an entry as LISTENING

2. Try to telnet to the port and send garbage. The server will disconnect you

> $ telnet localhost 1099
>
> Trying ::1...
>
> Connected to localhost.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.
>
> garbage
>
> Connection closed by foreign host.

3. There are a million other reasons why it may not be working. Firewall settings on the server, VPN port mapping, etc.. etc.. Until #1 and #2 are confirmed there isn't anything else to go on.

Comment: Note JMX uses **two** ports, `.jmxremote.port` default 1099 for the RMIregistry and `.jmxremote.rmi.port` default transient for the data, and both must be listening and reachable. But over VPN (unlike public/NAT access) I wouldn't expect a net-level problem.

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt/terminal then type: *jconsole*

then your jconsole will open and connect to activemq from it

*service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi*